# White line appears above toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a customized toolbar in my app and there is a white line that appears above the toolbar when I first launch the app as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLuze.jpg).

I don't even know what are the possible reasons for just a line.

XML for toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:visibility="visible">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlNormalToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/title_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|start">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_back_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back_white"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_close_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleToolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_toolbar_back_btn"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLogoMSC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_msc_small"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_notification"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_noti"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_notifications_st" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_notificationBadge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_12"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_mess"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_messages" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_messageBadge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_12"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_people"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_people_white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_filter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_bell"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/bell" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_bell_crossed"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/crossed_bell" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_create"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_tree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_2"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_1"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_confirm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_check_mark"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_alert"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_check_mark"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlSearchToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/sv_search_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_item_list_divider"
        style="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:queryHint="Search"
        android:visibility="visible">

    </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_search_back_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: post your `xml` layout file ??

Comment: This is due to iv_toolbar_bell and iv_toolbar_bell_crossed ImageView height and width. As you had put height and width 50 dp and your total toolbar height is only 48dp so it is extracting by 2 dp as a white space. Please try to change iv_toolbar_bell and iv_toolbar_bell_crossed height  by less than 48dp and then check.

Comment: thank you very much @ReadyAndroid.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be due to there being some space between the green nav bar and the top notification tray. Try adding some padding to move it to the top, it should remove the space :)